# Unable to fugure out the Regular Expression of the following

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, regular-language, automata

I've been working on Compiler Design lately and found Regular Expression quite tricky.
So I am making a lexical analyzer for which I need lexical specification.

I'm unable to figure out the RE of identifiers (Rules defined below):

- Maximum 4 characters
- At least 1 Alphabet

#### What I have already tried:

(letter|digit){4}  // I read that we can limit occurrence like this. But in this case, `11aa` will also be accepted.

*I think I can rewrite the above statement like this as well.*

(letter|digit)(letter|digit)(letter|digit)(letter|digit)

Please correct me if I'm wrong and thanks in advance!

Comment: Hints: 1. What would RE be if we require the first char to be alphabet?
2. Can you generalize it so it can be at any of four positions?

Comment: @ivan_onys I believe if we require the first char to be alphabet, the RE would be something like: (letter)(letter|digit)

Comment: (letter)(letter|digit){,3} | (letter|digit)(letter)(letter|digit){,2} | ... does it seems like a solution?

Comment: @ivan_onys Thanks a lot buddy. Please mention it in the Answer box and I'll accept your solution. Because, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing about this task is to make sure we have at least one letter.
And that letter could be at any of four positions.

```
(letter)(letter|digit){0,3} | (letter|digit)(letter)(letter|digit){0,2} | (letter|digit){2}(letter)(letter|digit){0,1} | (letter|digit){3}(letter)
```